# Canceling the previous keypress event

Tags: jquery, ajax

The problem is when I hit the enter key after writing a comment in an input box the message gets sent into the DB and then retrieved by a Ajax call.

Every thing goes out well, when I unfocused the input field and then focus it again and start typing new message and pressing enter then message gets sent two times, if I do that again the message gets sent 3 times and so on . what's wrong with the code? How can I resolve this ?

```
$(".type_comment").click(function(){
        container = $(this);

        if ($(this).val() == "Type a comment.")
        {
                    $(this).val("");
                    $(this).css({ 'font-size':'13px','opacity':'1' });          
        }
        nr_crt = container.attr("nr_crt");
        container.keyup(function(e)
            {
                code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13)
                    {
                            var chatmsg = container.val();
                            var comment_id = $("#main-photo"+nr_crt).attr("commentid");
                            var name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['username']); ?>;
                            $.post('../utility/postcomment.php', { comment: chatmsg, name: name, comment_id: comment_id } , 
                                function(output) {
                                });
                            code = null;
                            chatmsg = "";
                            container.val("");
                            var time = setTimeout(function(){
                            $.post('../utility/fetchcomments.php', { comment_id : comment_id , name : name} , 
                                function(results) {
                                    $(".comment_append"+nr_crt).append(results);
                                });
                            clearTimeout(time);
                            },500);
                    }
            });


    });
```

Comment: Attaching event handlers from within event handlers is a bad idea, and you're doing exactly that.

Comment: You're adding a new keyup handler every time you click `.type_comment`. You need to either unbind the click or only set your keyup function once ( outside the click handler )

Comment: well I tried putting the 'keyup' function outside the '.click' function but the container variable wouldn't get recognized ...

Comment: You can make the container a global variable , and this will help coz u are attaching listener multiple times also you can use unbind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".type_comment").click(function(){
    ...
    container.keyup(function(e){
```

will attach a new keyUp handler to the same containter each time you click it. Perhaps you want each new handler to fire once and then never again until re-attached? While it may not be considered the cleanest solution, [jQuery supports exactly that](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$(".type_comment").click(function(){
    ...
    container.one('keyup', function(e){
```

However, based on your description, most likely this is what you want:

```
$(".type_comment").each(function(){
    var container = $(this);
    var nr_crt = container.attr("nr_crt");
    ...
    container.click(...);
    container.keyup(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout to 0 instead of 500.  That will move it to the bottom of the list, but not give time to cache more enter keys.

Comment: it's not working....  I swear it's like keeping track of how many times I have unfocused the input :|